# custom npm config (.npmrc) path for npm command

Tags: node.js, devops

Is there a way to specify the custom .npmrc file path with npm command?

The context for the question: In a node js build and release pipeline (azure DevOps and Jenkins pipeline), I don't want to keep the .npmrc config which contains private registry path and _auth details in the git repository, Hence I want to generate it on the go with a different name, so that I can specify the file path along with npm command and use it and destroy it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The authorisation credentials could be stored in the pipeline secrets in either Jenkins or Azure DevOps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables

then you'll want to reference those ENV VARS inside your `.npmrc`